# "If" inside an always OR condition in the sensitivity list of the always block?

Tags: verilog

Is these two codes behave in the same way ?

```
always @(a == 1'b1) // I guess for this one, it's like a combinational if (AND gate logic : a AND 1).
    // code
```

and

```
always @(a) begin // I guess for this one, if a= 1 from the time 0,
                  // it won't go inside since there wouldn't be any change.
    if (a == 1) begin
    // code
    end
end
```

Is it true ?

It's a basic question but I'd like to know if I miss something, thank you!

Comment: I guess, both should behave the same. `always @(a).. if(a == 'b1) ...` is **shorthand** for `always @(a=='b1)`.

Comment: But for RTL you should never be using either of these and use `always @*`

Comment: I'm trying to understand RTL verilog but we cannot assign a reg in two different always blocks... With this condition, I can assign a reg value (with a "case" for example). Verilog is very hard to make something a bit complex with "enable" and "finish" bit.

Comment: "we cannot assign a reg in two different always blocks" No you can not because, what hardware do you know that can do this. an output driven from two different sections of code. which one is the active one? Easy problem to solve though two different values and use a mux to select the active one.

Comment: "Verilog is very hard to make something a bit complex with "enable" and "finish" bit." Well yes and no, your not building software so you have to figure out how it is done in hardware.  It is done in hardware by building a state machine, enable input moves from idle state to active state. finish flag is raised in final state before moving back to idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nope, both are not same.**

> Note that variables in the sensitivity list are considered as an event
>   and hence they are not executed, rather just change in the variable is
>   considered as a trigger to that event.

So the 1st always block

```
always @ (a==1'b1)
```

is same as :

```
always @ (a)
```

So **1st always block** will execute **with both a = 1 & 0**, whereas in **2nd case**, because of "if" condition, it will be executed **only with a = 1**

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get, what you meant by "inverse"?

Comment: `So 1st always block will execute with both a = 1 & 0, whereas in 2nd case, because of "if" condition, it will be executed only with a = 1` but the 1st always block will execute with only a=1. The second always block will execute at both, a<=>1or0.

Comment: Nope, that is not the case. Because you have written an expression in the event, does not that expression will be evaluated. So 1st always block is same as :

always @ (a)